# What is the best way to click the hyperlink based on the name using selenium WebDriver c#

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Below is the html code which is the structure of my .html page. I have a very long page but for sample purposes I have only three rows, whereas in the actual page I have hundreds

My question is: What is the best way to accomplish the following task:

How would I click on `Add to Basket` for the employee name John Steven (or any other name)?

```
 <table class="gvlist" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_ctl00_Features_Features_ContentList_gv">
        <tr class="gvheader">
            <th>
                Employee Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Topic
            </th>
            <th>
                Add Employee
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gvrow">
            <td>
                <a id="ctl00_employee_List_gv_ctl02_lnkPage" class="gvtitle" href="#" target="_blank">
                    Erich Schulz</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="topiclist">
                    <li class="ListItem" style="list-style: none"><a id="ctl00_employee_List_gv_ctl02_lbTopic"
                        class="InlineItemText" href="#">R&D</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="ctl00_employee_List_gv_ctl02_lnkSelect" href="#" class="addpage">Add to Basket
                    List</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gvrow">
            <td>
                <a id="ctl00_employee_List_gv_ctl03_lnkPage" class="gvtitle" href="#" target="_blank">
                    John Steven</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="topiclist">
                    <li class="ListItem" style="list-style: none"><a id="A2" class="InlineItemText" href="#">
                        Development</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="ctl00_employee_List_gv_ctl03_lnkSelect" href="#" class="addpage">Add to Basket
                    List</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gvrow">
            <td>
                <a id="ctl00_employee_List_gv_ctl04_lnkPage" class="gvtitle" href="#" target="_blank">
                    John McAfee</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="topiclist">
                    <li class="ListItem" style="list-style: none"><a id="A5" class="InlineItemText" href="#">
                        Tech</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a id="ctl00_employee_List_gv_ctl04_lnkSelect" href="#" class="addpage">Add to Basket
                    List</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there might be many possibilities but i will go with xpath

```
.//a[contains(.,'John McAfee')]/ancestor::tr//a[@class='addpage']
```

where 'John McAfee' can be passed via variable

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add to Basket")).click();